# Read excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

> Here i am trying to read the excel file and want to edit it if
>   required.
>
> ```
> //code here
> ```

```
      try
       {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));

            //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);  //ERROR HERE
            //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                 //code here
                }
            }
       }
```

> Blockquote
>   here i am getting error
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
>         at com.Edetails.Dao.ReadExcel.main(ReadExcel.java:27)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>         ... 1 more

Comment: Also Please help me how to edit the value in Cell for the same file i read.

Answer (score 0):

I was using POI jar of different versions. And also i forget to include the dom4j.jar to the project.

After adding that jar it is working fine. Please refer this [link](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) to get the latest poi jar.